# Camel only starts first route scheduled with quartz, at the wrong time

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

I have a Spring boot application with several camel routes that should start based on a quartz2's CronTrigger. For some reason, only the the route scheduled first is ever started, but it starts at the time scheduled for the last route.

1. route one: mytime - 1h
2. route two: mytime

Only route one is started, at mytime.

I have made a minimal example. Because my routes are supposed to check the contents of a database table and export part of it, in my example the routes will check the table and log the most recent date found in a column set in the properties.

Routebuilder:

```
/**
* Starts a list of routes that have been scheduled in application.yml
*/
@Component
public class ScheduledRoutesRouteBuilder extends SpringRouteBuilder {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduledRoutesRouteBuilder.class);
  private static final String BEAN_CHECKDB = "bean:checkDBBean?method=getFirstRecord(%s, %s)";

  @Autowired
  private RoutesDefinition routesDefinition;

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    routesDefinition.getScheduledRoutes().stream()
    .forEach(route -> createScheduledRoute(route));
}

  private void createScheduledRoute(RouteDefinition aRoute) {
    from(aRoute.getSchedule())
    .routeId(aRoute.getRouteId())
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, LOG, "Kickstarting export route: " + aRoute.getRouteId() + " - schedule: " + aRoute.getSchedule())
    .to(String.format(BEAN_CHECKDB, aRoute.getDbTableName(), aRoute.getReferenceDateColumnName()));
    System.out.println("Configured export route: " + aRoute.getRouteId() + " - schedule: " + aRoute.getSchedule());
  }
}
```

application.yml:

```
# Schedules
scheduleFirst: 0 39 * * * ?
scheduleSecond: 0 41 * * * ?

scheduledRoutes:
  - routeId: MonthProcessingRoute
      dbTableName: month
      referenceDateColumnName: acceptatiedatum
      schedule: quartz2://CronTrigger?cron=${scheduleFirst}
  - routeId: WeekProcessingRoute
      dbTableName: week
      referenceDateColumnName: acceptatiedatum
      schedule: quartz2://CronTrigger?cron=${scheduleSecond}
```

Log:

> Configured export route: MonthProcessingRoute - schedule:
>   quartz2://CronTrigger?cron=0 39 * * * ?
>
> Configured export route: WeekProcessingRoute - schedule: quartz2://CronTrigger?cron=0 41 * * * ?
>
> 2018-03-20 05:37:33 INFO  tryouts-spring-camel ivana.StartUp -   - 
>   - Started StartUp in 2.507 seconds (JVM running for 3.238)
>
> 2018-03-20 05:41:00 INFO  tryouts-spring-camel ivana.routebuilders.ScheduledRoutesRouteBuilder -   -  - Kickstarting
>   export route: MonthProcessingRoute - schedule:
>   quartz2://CronTrigger?cron=0 39 * * * ?
>
> Most recent date found in database table month: 2017-11-05 15:31:00.0

Comment: Are you sure you are using unique group and timerName in your Camel routes, eg they should not both be called CronTrigger.

Comment: Yess! @Claus Ibsen, thank you. Do you want to make it into an answer of should i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure to use unique triggerName/groupName for each of your Camel routes. It looks like you use the same name `CronTrigger` in both routes. Change that to be unique names, and it should work.